# Insert custom number of new rows in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

When right-clicking on a row in a Google Sheet, I get the option to "Insert 1 Above" or "Insert 1 Below".

How do I insert any number of new rows?

Answer (score 5):

Select multiple rows, right click on any selected row, and you will now see options to "Insert X above/below" where X is the number of rows you have selected. As an example:

> **In order to insert 10 new rows:**
>
> - Select 10 rows
> - Right click on any of the selected rows
> - Select "Insert 10 above" or "Insert 10 below"

You can also select multiple rows, and then open the *Insert* menu. The options will also be available there. As an example:

> **In order to insert 10 new rows:**
>
> - Select 10 rows
> - Click on the *Insert* menu on the top menu bar
> - Select "10 Rows above" or "10 Rows below"